# Can I get Outlook's "find related messages in this conversation" to ignore slight changes to the subject line?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

In our office we need to classify every email. This isn't a problem if you do that on Outlook, but if you use the "Blackberry for Work" app then it appends the classification to the subject line.

As a result, Outlook's "find related messages in this conversation" breaks because it considers all of these as the same conversation:

> **Subject:** Don't forget your TPS reports
> **Subject:** RE: Don't forget your TPS reports
> **Subject:** FW: Don't forget your TPS reports

but this one as a completely different conversation:

> **Subject:** RE: Don't forget your TPS reports [internal]

Is there any way I can make Outlook ignore the suffix when displaying related messages?

(I did look at VBA as a solution but I don't want to rewrite the subject line and [`MailItem.ConversationTopic`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/exchange-server/exchange-10/ms527833(v=exchg.10)) is sadly read-only)

Comment: Is it acceptable to search by subject line instead of using the "find related messages" feature? The search query `subject:"Don't forget your TPS reports"` would catch all the messages you listed.

Comment: @EngineerToast That's not a bad approach if I get no other answers, thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid that it might be by design and we could not make changes to it. You could try EngineerToast's method as a wordaround.